# Managing processes in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, systems-programming

I am trying to test how to create and manage processes with a program what should create a process and execute a command 2 times (each time executing a different command).

What I am trying to do exactly:

- Create a new PID
- Print the PID
- Execute a command
- Exit

Weirdly, when I execute 1 command, it works fine but when I execute the routine twice, the 2nd command is being executed twice also. Meaning that 3 commands get executed.

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



void launch_command(char command[]) {
  pid_t pid;

  pid = fork();
  if(pid==0)

  {
    printf("Creating process %d from %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
    system(command);
    exit(0);

  }
  else {
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
       perror("Error while creating a new process");
  }

}

int main () {
  printf("Root process: %d\n",getpid());

  launch_command("/bin/ls -l");
  while(wait(NULL) >= 0);

  launch_command("/bin/date");
  while(wait(NULL) >= 0);

  return 0;

}
```

The output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Root process: 8924
Creating process 8925 from 8924
Creating process 8928 from 8926
Sun 13 Nov 2022 23:54:51 EST
total 128
-rwxr-xr-x  1 gg  staff  49784 13 Nov 23:54 a.out
-rw-r--r--  1 gg  staff   3499 11 Nov 10:59 create_process.c
Creating process 8931 from 8924
Sun 13 Nov 2022 23:54:51 EST
```

Could someone explain me this behaviour?

The desired result should be:

```
$ ./a.out 
Root process: 8924
Creating process 8925 from 8924
total 128
-rwxr-xr-x  1 gg  staff  49784 13 Nov 23:54 a.out
-rw-r--r--  1 gg  staff   3499 11 Nov 10:59 create_process.c
Creating process 8931 from 8924
Sun 13 Nov 2022 23:54:51 EST
```

Comment: Why does `launch_command` call `fork` again in the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the second call to `fork` is creating too many processes.

After the first call to `launch_command` returns, there will be both a parent process and a freshly made child process. They will both call the second `launch_command` function, spawning two more processes that call `system`, and then an additional process each, that again return from the function as well.

There will be four total processes that execute the second `while` loop.

Remove the second `fork` call, and use the same value of `pid` again to check for failure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void launch_command(const char *command)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (0 == pid) {
        printf("Creating process %d from %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        system(command);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if (-1 == pid) {
        perror("Error while creating a new process");
    }

    while (wait(NULL) >= 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Root process: %d\n", getpid());

    launch_command("/bin/ls -l");
    launch_command("/bin/date");
}
```